# List all X coordinates by given a Y coordinate in a line profiles by DM scripting

Tags: dm-script

For a line profile (curve), I want to reach that list all X coordinates that corresponding a Y coordinate by given this Y coordinate. And I could get the minimum and maximum values of these x coordinates.  Here supposed I want to list all the X coordinates corresponding y=8, is this correct or any other better way? Thx

```
 Number minx, maxx
    Image front=:getfrontimage()

    GetSize( front, xsize, ysize )

    for (i=0; i<xsize; i++)

                {
                    x= getpixel(front, i, 8)
                 minx=min(x)
          maxx=max(x)

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script becomes wrong when you use the `min` and `max`, because you can not get a minimum/maximum of a single value (or rather, it is *always* that value). What you want to do is likely:

```
image spec := RealImage("Test",4,100)
spec = trunc(Random()*10)
number v = 8

ClearResults()
number nCh = spec.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
for( number i=0; i<nCh; i++)
{
    if( v == sum(spec[i,0]) )
        Result("\n Value "+ v +" @ " + i )
}
```

(The `sum()` is needed here a a trick to convert an image-expression to a single value.)

---

However, going pixel-by-pixel in script can be slow. Whenever possible, try to code with image-expressions, because they are much faster (for big images).
I therefore often utilize a trick: I threshold an image for the value I search for, and then iterate over that mask as long as it is not all-zero. The `max(img,x,y)` command will return the *first* maximum if there are multiple, so I get an ordered list.

```
image spec := RealImage("Test",4,100)
spec = trunc(Random()*10)
spec.ShowImage()

number v = 8
image mask = (spec==v)?1:0

ClearResults()
while( 0<sum(mask) )
{
    number x,y
    max(mask,x,y)
    Result("\n Value " + v +" @ " + x )
    mask[x,0]=0
}
```

---

Edit: Answering the question of the comment below.

#### This is how one gets the ZLP maximum (position and value) from a line-profile in calibrated values.

Precursor: DM contains all data as simple arrays and values (real or integer). These are the real data and unrelated to any calibrations. You see these values if you toggle the "calibration" checkbox off in the Image Status palette:
[image: Uncalibrated display]
These are the values all script commands etc. will use, i.e. positions are always *indices* (starting from 0) and values are the raw numeric values stored.

These images or spectra are calibrated by defining an origin and scale (and unit) for each dimensional axis as well as the intensity (=value). These triplets of values can be found in the image display info of data:
[image: Calibration values]

Only when the "Show calibrated values" checkbox is checked, is the data *displayed* in calibrated values. However, the real values remain unchanged. Just the scale/origin values are used to convert the numbers.
[image: Calibrated values]

If you want to use a script to use calibrated values, then you have to perform the same conversions in you script yourself.
Here is the example:

```
image spectrum := GetFrontImage()

number xScale = spectrum.ImageGetDimensionScale(0)  // 0 for X dimension
number xOrigin = spectrum.ImageGetDimensionOrigin(0)
string xUnit = spectrum.ImageGetDimensionUnitString(0)

number iScale = spectrum.ImageGetIntensityScale()
number iOrigin = spectrum.ImageGetIntensityOrigin()
string iUnit = spectrum.ImageGetIntensityUnitString()

string info = "\n"
info += "Image ["+spectrum.ImageGetLabel()+"]:"
info += "\n\t Dimension calibration: nCh * " + xScale + " + " + xOrigin + " [" + xUnit + "]"
info += "\n\t Intensity calibration: (value - " + iOrigin + ") * " + iScale +" [" + iUnit + "]"
Result(info)

// Find ZLP maximum (uncalibrated values)
number maxP_ch, dummy, maxV_raw
maxV_raw = max(spectrum,maxP_ch,dummy)
info = "\n"
info += "\n\t The maximum position is at channel index: " + maxP_ch 
info += "\n\t The maximum Value at maximum position is: " + maxV_raw 
Result(info)

number maxP_cal = xOrigin + xScale * maxP_ch
number maxV_cal = (maxV_raw - iOrigin) * iScale
info = "\n"
info += "\n\t The maximum position is at : " + maxP_cal
info += "\n\t The maximum Value is       : " + maxV_cal 
Result(info)
```

Note the different calibration formulas between dimensional calibration and intensity calibration!

Comment: If I just want to find the minimum and maximum values of X coordinates and Y coordinates whole spectrum (including the negative value), for example, for spectrum, minimum X coordinate=-200, maximum X coordinate=800,  minimum Y coordinate=-10, maximum Y coordinate =1885, I tried to use get size() function, but it shows the pixel number of whole image 2048 and 2048, does not give the minimum and maximum coordinates value

Comment: @together You mean the X-range of your profile? For this you need to read the *calibration* (scale & origin) and perform the conversion from uncalibrated channel number to calibrated value.  For the X-axis this is ImageGetDimensionScale() and ImageGetDimensionOrigin(). For the Y-axis (which really is the intensity value at the pixel) you need ImageGetIntensityScale() and ImageGetIntensityOrigin().

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is what I want.  For example, I have a EELS ZLP spectrum, the highest point  of ZLP or you highest Y coordinate is 233345 counts,  I would like to use script to get this " 23345 counts". I used converttofloat() function to spectrum to real image, it still can not directly read the highest and lowest coordinate values. Will try your command. Thx again.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Not really like that.  For example, I have a EELS ZLP spectrum, the highest point  of ZLP or you highest Y coordinate is 233345 counts,  I would like to use script to get this " 233345 counts".  The spectrum  ImageGetIntensityScale() ,you can set as 250000 or 300000 . But they are not the highest coordinate value, they are just display range.  I remember I can directly read this from the intensity curve, but not sure could not from EELS ZLP. I used converttofloat() to change image type to real image, it is still not working.